# How to create a custom property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to create a custom property meaning rather using

```
<Style x:Key="ABC" TargetType="Rectangle">
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

I like to have something like Rectangle and assign it an ID so later when it is dropped on Canvas I can retrieve its ID.

```
<Style x:Key="ABC" TargetType="Rectangle">
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
    **<Setter Property="ID" Value="1234567890-ABC"/>**
</Style>
```

How can I define that custom property?

Regards,
Amit

Comment: do you want to define another class like rectangle and then define a property on it?

Comment: Use `Tag` property or look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940597/how-to-create-a-dependency-property-on-an-existing-control

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a custom attached property in a separate class:

```
public class Prop : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IDProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ID", typeof(string), typeof(Prop), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static void SetID(UIElement element, string value)
    {
        element.SetValue(IDProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetID(UIElement element)
    {
        return (string)element.GetValue(IDProperty);
    }
}
```

Then you can use this:

```
<Setter Property="local:Prop.ID" Value="1234567890-ABC"/>
```

`local` must be defined in the root element of your XAML appromimately like this:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AttPropTest"
```

where `AttPropTest` is the namespace of the assembly.

In code, you can determine the ID with `Prop.GetID(myRect)`.

Comment: Hi Fmunkert, it was a great sample so I followed all the steps but I guess something I'm missing here cause when I run it i get an error as (in XAML) **Cannot convert the value in attribute 'Property' to object of type 'System.Windows.DependencyProperty'. **